# iOS - Why does getConfiguredSSIDs always return the last network profile created?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, networking, wifi

I have a function that creates a Hotspot 2.0/Passpoint profile.

**Create network profile**

```
NEHotspotConfigurationManager.shared.apply(hotspotConfig) {[unowned self] (error) in
 print("Error 1: ",error?.localizedDescription as Any)
 print("Error 2: ", error as Any)
 if let error = error {
  print("My Error: ", error)
  successCallback([false])
 } else {
  NSLog("successfully installed ")
  successCallback([true])
 }
}
```

It works.  I can authenticate without issues. `hotspotConfig` contains all the configuration to create this profile.

I then have a function to get all configured SSID's or domain names the app has created.

**Read array of profiles**

```
NEHotspotConfigurationManager.shared.getConfiguredSSIDs {
(ssidsArray) in
for ssid in ssidsArray {
 print(ssid)
}
 }
```

**For clarification -**

A HS 2.0 or passpoint profile is identified by the domain name e.g. example.com
While a normal Wifi config is identified by the actual SSID name.

The problem is that the `print` statement always print the last profile the app has configured.
For example, I create 2 profiles with 2 different domains (example1.com and example2.com).  It would print example2.com.

It's almost like it deletes the previous profile.  Not sure why..

Ref:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotconfigurationmanager/2866695-getconfiguredssids

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotconfigurationmanager

Comment: did you get any solution?

Comment: Nope - had to implement somewhat of a local check instead.  Did submit a report to Apple via Feedback Assistance but heard nothing back yet.

Comment: I raised DTS ticket with apple, lets see their reply, BTW how did you manage locally? Can you connect to previously configured HS2.0 wifi network with your local change?

Comment: Great. I used AsyncStorage to keep a record if a profile is installed on an event.  Now if the user goes to Settings and removes said profile manually, this wont detect it. 

I have an Install button, on click it installs HS 2.0 profile and displays Remove button.  A check to AsyncStorage has the logic to display install or remove.

And yes, no issues connecting.

Comment: Settings in the sense are you referring to iOS Settings app? if so can we see the HS 2.0 profile which was adding using "NEHotspotConfigurationManager.shared.apply" method, I couldn't see added profiles in the settings app. And after you install multiple profiles for different domains(lets say example1.com,example2.com respectively ), can you connect to first HS2.0 wifi network with example1.com after configuring for example2.com?

Comment: Correct, Settings app. I was referring to Android for some reason in my last comment where you can see the profile installed.

On iOS as you said, you cannot. Installing multiple profiles does not work fluently or as I expected.  The last installed profile is the active one and the only active one. If you have 2 profiles installed, the second profile can connect to an AP while the first cannot. Different domains or not. 

If you remove the second profile, the first profile becomes active again. This has been my findings anyway, may be different for you.

Comment: I do have an access point setup with HS 2.0 configured on it so this is how I do my testing (Cambium). I wanted to have different profiles with the same domain but different credentials for TTLS and could not get it working due to the issue above I mentioned.  I then tested with different domain for clarification and ran into the same issue.

Comment: A few other issues I came across to mention; if you have HS 2.0 configured on your AP and you configure an 802.1x profile with an SSID.  When you call getConfiguredSSID's - instead of returning the SSID against the 802.1x profile - it returns the domain of the HS 2.0 configuration on the AP - very weird. Even if this is the only profile installed.  I sent this to Apple as a bug report.

Comment: Yes that's correct, we can connect to only most recent configured HS2.0 wifi network irrespective of multiple configurations for the the different domains. Apple should allow developers to configure multiple HS2.0 networks for different domains(like the way .mobileconfig profile does).

Comment: "getConfiguredSSIDs"  they have documented (Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotconfigurationmanager/2866695-getconfiguredssids) that it can return domains for HS2.0 configurations

Comment: Exactly - when reading the documentation, it got my hopes up that it would work but in practise it would not.  As you said, getConfiguredSSID's has the option to return domains from a HS 2.0 or SSID from 802.1x; depending on what you set in the parameter, this had no effect at all for me.   If I hear back from Apple or manage to get something working, I'd notify you on this.  Appreciate if you do the same - Apple is not great when it comes to bug reporting and the time it takes for them to reply :)